# Accessing page public property from user control in master page

Tags: asp.net, reflection, user-controls, master-pages

I am trying to access a public property of a page inside a master page from a user control which is also inside the same master page. Most of the examples I have seen recommend that I place the value from the property in a hidden element on the page and access it by getting a reference to the master page and using something along the lines

```
Dim mstr As MasterPage = Page.Master
Dim element = mstr.FindControl("hiddenField1"), HiddenField)
```

or otherwise put the value in cookie, URL etc and read it from the user control.

However I was able to get the value using

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim mstr As MasterPage = Page.Master
    Return CallByName(mstr.Page, "ProductCounter", [Get])
End Sub
```

Since my solution works by

> CallByBame basically gives you "late binding" which is "figuring out
>   the method at run-time" as opposed to "early binding" where the
>   compiler figures it out for you.

[from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299939/394381)

I was wondering, considering the other solutions. Is the second way still an inferior method of accomplishing this goal considering performance, security, type safety etc?

EDIT: The answer by [Icarus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10951374/394381) works for asp..net web application but not for asp.net websites. I am looking for an answer which works for the later.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need not use reflection at all. You should be able to do something like this in your control (C#, sorry):

```
//Assume "MyPage" is the Page inside the MasterPage
MyPage myPage = this.Page as MyPage;
if(myPage!=null)
{
    var publicProperty = myPage.PublicProperty;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Providing a simplified Example.

Site.Master:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">        
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<%--this is the user control on the MasterPage--%>
<uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
```

Say you have another Page, called "About" that uses this Site.Master and this "About" page has a public property called "PublicProperty as so:

```
public string PublicProperty {
        get { 
            return ViewState["Key"] as string; 
        } 
        set { 
            ViewState["Key"] = value; 
        } 
}
```

Now, in your WebUserControl, you can do this safely, say on Page_Load:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        About p = this.Page as About;
        if (p != null){
            var prop = p.PublicProperty;
            //Do Something cool with it
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Icarus, thanks for your response. I tried replicating your solution but I was not able to access the About object from the user control. How are you accomplishing this? No need to be sorry about using C#, I am proficient in both languages :)

Comment: It works for me just fine and it should work for you. You may not get this working if you created your project as a "Website" as opposed to creating a regular project of type ASP.NET application.

Comment: Hi Icarus, You are right, I should have been more clear in my question. I am building a asp.net website not a web application.