# .NET: retrieve value from dynamic property of objects in array

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm basically trying to implement part of the logic that some of the ASP.Net controls (e.g. `DropDownList`) use in order to accept a generic data source which is iterated over and each row consumed by calling properties specified by the user.

This is in VB.Net. Example follows:

```
Dim myObject As Object = getUnknownObject()
Dim propertyName As String = getUnknownPropertyNameForObject()

'Now given that myObject is an array of objects which possess the property given by propertyName '

For Each i As Object In myObject
   Dim valueOfProperty As String = invokePropertyOfObject(myObject, propertyName)
   'Do something with value'
Next i
```

I'm looking for an implementation of `invokePropertyOfObject` which will return he property's value. I'd like to be mindful of the fact that the dynamic property is called in a loop, so there could be performance issues associated with using reflection in this way.

Does anyone know what the ideal way of doing what I'm trying to do? If possible I'd like a way to only perform the dynamic property lookup once and use it repeatedly during the loop. Is it possible to do this, bearing in mind that while the object is unknown, each object in the array is of the same type.

Comment: To get the value of property you need an instance, so you are going to have to call it for each object. You could do this but it's very fragile. If the objects are yours, decoratimng them with suitable attributes and then finding them by that would be a better way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the PropertyInfo object for the type of your array before the loop and then you can use the propertyInfo.GetValue() method for each element in the array. That way you're only finding the property once but are able to get the value for each record.

Comment: Just tried using both CallByName and calling via the PropertyInfo object. PropertyInfo is ~10x as fast when looping over a data set of 1,000,000 KeyValuePairs

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use `myObject.Property()` directly if you have no other choice. It would be best to transform the object into the correct type in order to use the property.

This is your other option:

```
Dim value as String = CallByName(myObject, propertyName, CallType.Get)
```

Comment: CallByName will be invoked once for each object in the array. Is there a significant overhead of doing this? Given that there may be many objects in the array, what's an efficient way of invoking the same property on each one of them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267588/disadvantages-of-callbyname-function-in-vb-net