# Accessing subclass or subproperty using CallByName

Tags: vb.net, callbyname

I can access class' subvalues using **CallByName** (In other words, I can get `Class.SubValue` with it).
But I get error when I want to get `Class.SUBCLASS.SubValue` using CallByName.
Is it possible to do it using CallByName (or by using smtg else)?

Here's a typical code:

```
Class Class1
    Public someVariable as Long=123 'now "Class1" has "someVariable" 
End Class
Class Class2
    Public subClass as new Class1   'now "Class2" has a SUBCLASS "Class1" 
End Class

Sub Test()
    Dim c1 as New Class1, c2 as New Class2
        'This works fine, and I can get c1.someVariable. It's OK.
    a=CallByName(c1,"someVariable",CallType.Get)
        'But I get error here... and I can't get c2.subClass.someVariable
    b=CallByName(c2,"subClass.someVariable",CallType.Get)
End Sub
```

**-- EDIT: Here is the actual question. --**

I want to LOAD parameters from a file to form's controls, and in file the parameters are written like this:
`<ControlName>.<Property>=<Value> | TextBox1.Text=SomeText | Button2.Left=1234`
And I get error when I use:
`CallByName(MyForm, "<ControlName>.<Property>", CallType.Set, "<Value>")`

How can I fix my problem (using CallByName or smtg else)?

Comment: What's the point of using this legacy and obsolete way of accessing members? Is just `c2.subClass.someVariable` not enough? ;)

Comment: In instance, check this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267588/disadvantages-of-callbyname-function-in-vb-net

Comment: `c2.subClass.someVariable` is not enough, because I need to change my form's control's **texts** and **sizes**. For example, I need to change `MyForm.TextBox1.Left`, `MyForm.Button2.Text` and smtg alike it.

Comment: And...? What if you make the `TextBox` class field internal or public? What prevents you of accessing it?!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I know what are you talking about :) But I want to load that values from a file (that values from file are alike this: `TextBox1.Left=10` ), and set that values to my controls (`MyForm.TextBox1.Left=10`).

Comment: Actually I don't find a reasonable point to use your approach, sorry :(

Comment: Two *get* calls are required here.  One for the subClass property, another for the someVariable property.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, but how can I get subClass (from its string name)? Clarify, please.

Answer (score 2):

i used this simple recoursive function

```
  Function RecursiveGetValue(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Data As Object) As Object
If Name.Contains(".") = True Then
  RecursiveGetValue = RecursiveGetValue(Name.Substring(Name.IndexOf(".") + 1), CallByName(Data, Name.Split(".")(0), CallType.Get))
Else
  RecursiveGetValue = CallByName(Data, Name, CallType.Get)
End If
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar. I wanted to be able to use dot notation in SQL column names to recursively populate an object hierarchy.

```
Sub PopulateData(r As SqlDataReader)
    For i As Integer = 0 To r.FieldCount - 1
        If Len(r(i)) > 0 Then
            Try
                Dim ob As Object = Me
                Dim name As String = r.GetName(i)

                While InStr(name, ".") > 0
                    ob = CallByName(ob, Split(name, ".")(0), CallType.Get)
                    name = name.Substring(InStr(name, "."))
                End While

                CallByName(ob, name, CallType.Set, r(i))


            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Missing property: {0}", r.GetName(i))

            End Try

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```